# Getting logs out of Laravel Horizon running in docker in supervisor

Tags: laravel, docker, supervisord, laravel-horizon

I use [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/horizon) to process jobs in my Laravel application with the help of Supervisor. The whole setup runs on docker in ECS. On the host node of ECS (managed by Fargate) I have datadog agents running on it, which will grab the stdout/stderr of the container and put it into datadog (so I can access the logs centrally).

What I noticed is that I am not getting any logs out of the jobs that is processing. Even simple `print("test");` in the job code does not go to the stdout.

Here's my setup:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.11

RUN apk add \
        --no-cache \
        --update \
        ...snipped...
        py-pip \
    && pip install supervisor \
    && pip install supervisor-stdout

WORKDIR /app

...snipped...
```

The service definition for this in yaml looks like this:

```
version: '2'

    services:

      my-app-horizon:
        container_name: my-app-horizon
        image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE}
        mem_limit: 1024M
        command: "supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/horizon.conf"
        ...snipped...
```

And here's the content of my `horizon.conf`:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:horizon]
priority = 100
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /app/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=apache
stopwaitsecs=3600
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true

[eventlistener:stdout]
priority = 1
command = supervisor_stdout
buffer_size = 100
events = PROCESS_LOG
result_handler = supervisor_stdout:event_handler
```

Any idea what I might be missing? What can't I get logs out of the jobs processed by horizon in docker via supervisor?

Answer (score 2):

A colleaque of mine informed me that, since we're using docker, we can by-pass supervisor and just run the horizon artisan command directly as the entrypoint of the container.

So, I removed all things related to supervisor and my service yaml is simplified to the following and the logs are coming into datadog:

```
version: '2'

    services:

      my-app-horizon:
        container_name: my-app-horizon
        image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE}
        mem_limit: 1024M
        command: "/app/artisan horizon"
        ...snipped...
```

Comment: That's true, but how can I get access to the dashboard?